# core graphics text clipping

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I have the following code working that draws a white rectangle and clips it the string "TEXT".

[image]

```
CGContextSaveGState(c);
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0.0f, rect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1.0f, -1.0f);
CGContextSelectFont(c, "Helvetica-Bold", 16, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextClip);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(c, x, y, "TEXT", strlen("TEXT"));
CGContextClip(c);
CGContextFillRect(c, fillRect);
CGContextRestoreGState(c);
```

But I want it to clip so that it only draws outside of the text.  How do I do that?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I've been trying to do the same thing.

Comment: It seems like the best solution is to draw the text offscreen and use it to generate a mask.

Comment: I'm rendering to a PDF context, though, so I really don't want to involve an intermediate bitmap...